# TypeOrm consulta com Inner Join está vindo vazia

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, inner-join, typeorm

Fiz duas tabelas, `Usuario` 1 : N  `Produto`

Fiz um inner join com o TypeOrm, porém estava vindo um array vazio, então peguei a query que ele estava gerando para analisar melhor. Quando joguei a query no Dbeaver funcionou perfeitamente, os dados vieram certinhos, porém, somente quando chamo pela aplicação ela vem vazia, alguém poderia me ajudar??

Query gerada quando uso o `getQuery()`

`SELECT "Produto"."nome", "usuario"."nome" FROM "tb_produto" "Produto" INNER JOIN "tb_usuario" "usuario" ON "usuario"."id" =  "Produto"."id_usuario"`

#### Query que vem com o array vazio na aplicação

```
const produtos = await createQueryBuilder(Produto)
                .innerJoinAndSelect('tb_usuario', 'usuario','usuario.id = Produto.id_usuario')
                .select('Produto.nome, usuario.nome')
                .getMany();
```

#### Imagem de auxílio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Espero que já tenha conseguido resolver o problema. Mas para aqueles que cairem nessa pergunta, tente substituir getMany() por getRawMany()

Para mais informações: https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder